# Netbeans bug, Doesn't work Non-printable characters

Tags: java, netbeans, jvi

I am currently using Netbeans with jVi (vim plugin). But after I install vim plugin, I can't disable Non-printable characters

Menu:
View -> Show Non-printable Characters (this menu doesn't work) nothing changed.

I want to remove this paragraph character. Please help me!

[How to remove this paragraph character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sGJg.png)

Comment: If you think it's a bug you should open a bug with jVi.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca after uninstall plugin, that menu still doesn't work. What should I do? also How to restore default settings ?

Comment: Now it looks like a netbeans problem, so you should open a bug with them instead. Also, what version of netbeans is it?

Comment: Anyway a quick and dirty solution may be just reinstalling the whole thing.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as it is not about computer programming.

Comment: @tgdavies to be fair (and for the future), questions about tools used for programming (case in point: netbeans) are explicitly [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This question is not perfect, but the fact that it's not about computer programming is not *the* reason to close it.

Comment: Thanks @FedericoklezCulloca, I've retracted the close vote.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks man! I delete cache folder then solved :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In NetBeans, use `:set nolist`, just as you would in vim. Of course you will need to reinstall the jVi plugin.

Not being able to use the menu after uninstall sounds like jVi left things funny. It could be that you didn't disable jVi before uninstalling, see `Menu > Tools > jVi`. I just disabled jVi, used `Menu > View > ShowNonPrintableCharacters` ok. Unfortunately, un-install doesn't give jVi a chance clean up.